# Error using load data local infile using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this file in csv trying to import to  using load data infile syntax. but I am stuck with this error in syntax.
I tried every thing  but no luck.Any help would be appreciated.

```
string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/explortest.csv' INTO  test.tickets FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\r\n' ignore 1 lines  ";
```

## ERROR

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test.tickets FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'  lines terminated by '
'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string strLoadData = "...";
```

The C# compiler will look for escape sequences in *strLoadData* and replace them with special characters. Thus your `\r\n` would be interpreted by C# as "*new line*" and "*line feed*" characters. But you need MySQL to read "\r\n" not "*new line*" and "*line fead*" characters - to apply it's own escape sequences interpretation.

Long story short: replace `\r\n` with `\\r\\n`

Answer (score 0):

Add TABLE After INTO

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/explortest.csv' 
INTO TABLE test.tickets FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\r\n' ignore 1 lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the line terminates character in file. Are you sure that is `\r\n`? Maybe you have `\n` or `\r` as line termination on your file.

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). I'm copying a part of this page below:

> **Note**
>
> If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' to read the file properly, because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator. Some programs, such as WordPad, might use \r as a line terminator when writing files. To read such files, use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'.